# add lines for each 3 lines

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a document like this

```
1 0.2
1 0.3
1 0.1
2 0.8
2 0.5
2 0.3
```

I want to add the lines if the first column are the same and output something like this

```
1 0.6
2 1.6
```

How can I do this with awk? Or maybe it is easier with other tools?

PD: the first column are the same for each 3 lines always, so maybe make an array that adds $2 until line count goes to 3 and print? something like this `awk 'BEGIN {x=0,n=1} {n++,x=x+$3}'`but with some condition?

Answer (score 1):

We can build an array of "first value, sum of second value" and then after the whole file has been read in we can print out the results

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END { for (v in a) { print v,a[v]}}' datafile
```

If you want the output sorted then the easiest way is to pipe that through sort:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END { for (v in a) { print v,a[v]}}' datafile | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all'; 

my %sum_of;
while ( <DATA> ) {
   my ( $key, $value ) = m/(\d+) ([\d\.]+)/; 
   $sum_of{$key} += $value;
}

print "$_ $sum_of{$_}\n" for sort keys %sum_of;


__DATA__
1 0.2
1 0.3
1 0.1
2 0.8
2 0.5
2 0.3
```

This gives the desired output.

As a one liner:

```
perl -lne '($key, $value) = split; $sum_of{$key}+=$value; END {print "$_ $sum_of{$_}" for sort keys %sum_of}'
```